# Intermittent issue with jsch while trying to run a shell script

Tags: java, jsch

I am trying to execute a shell script (which is in a different unix server). Now i have seen that sometimes it was unable to execute that script. As that script takes very long time to execute, therefore i cannot read/wait for the output. just wanted to make sure that the script has ran every time.

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();
String cmd="cd /blackduck/tfs/tfsconnector; ./runTFSConnector_web ;
session = jsch.getSession("UserID", hostIP, 22);
session.setUserInfo(new SSHUserInfo("Password"));
session.connect();

channel = session.openChannel("exec");
((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(cmd);

channel.connect();


while((!channel.isClosed()){

     Thread.sleep(3000);
}
```

I have added the while loop just b'coz of channel to be closed.

Kindly give some solution. any suggestion will be highly appreciable.

Comment: You say that "sometimes it was unable to execute that script". What happens in this case? How do you know? Did you get any error messages? What did they say?

Comment: @Kenster Its not throwing any error message at all. but in my unix server i can see the script was not executed. Is there any way to confirm that the script has ran successfully or reattempt if it is fail.

Comment: @Kenster And also some times i have seen that channel.getExitStatus() != 0 . means channel is not getting closed properly.